# Unable to connect to SSH

Tags: centos, ssh

At first I apologize for my newbie question. 
I just installed darkstat on my centos server using the following command to monitor traffics.

```
yum install darkstat
darkstat -i eth0
```

Unfortunately after that, the ssh is not accessible anymore and I'm stuck behind the door! All websites and the control panel are fine.
Both the SSH port and my IP are in firewall allowed list.
How can I get the SSH back?

Comment: Is it a physical server?  VPS, and who provides it?  Containerised, if so?

Comment: It's a vmware vps. I'm the provider!

Comment: I presume VMWARE has some equivalent of logical console access.  You'll probably need to arrange that, reboot single-user, and fix things (ie, remove darkstat) that way.

Comment: I already did that and rebooted the vm but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed.
Removing the darkstat using the console would be the fastest solution.